# Why can I only use SSI with relative path?

Tags: cgi, include-path, server-side-includes, ssi

I just read a little tutorial on SSI and managed to show what I wantedbut I'd like to use an absolute path to point at this file, but for some reason I can only do it with a relative path. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<!--#include virtual="/menubar/bar.html" -->
```

Works

But when I use:

```
<!--#include virtual="http://chusmix.com/menubar/bar.html" -->
```

I get this error: [an error occurred while processing this directive]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically SSIs must refer to local filesystem paths. What you are trying to use isn't an absolute filesystem path - it's an HTTP URL.

Comment: ahh ok thanks I'll delete it and write another that makes sense